# Как заменить первый пробел в строке на Таб?

Tags: powershell

Как разбить данную строку первым пробелом от начала (после ivan.ivanov) и склеить её знаком табуляции. Количество пробелов в строке может быть разным. Нужно что бы строка всегда делилась от начала первым пробелом.

```
'ivan.ivanov 27 марта 2019 г.,10:15:57' -replace ...

'petr.petrov 27 марта 2019 г.,10:15:57 30' -replace ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'ivan.ivanov 27 марта 2019 г.,10:15:57' -replace '(^[\w\.]+)\s(.*)', "`$1`t`$2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Все просто.
Для замены ВСЕХ пробелов в строке:

```
$string.Replace(' ', [char]9)
```

Для замены ПЕРВОГО пробела:

```
$string.Insert($string.IndexOf(' '), [char]9)
```

В данном случае `[char]9` - символ табуляции.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а он всегда будет обращаться именно к первому пробелу от начала? тут важно - хоть 3 пробела в строке хоть 10. Ответ нравится...

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko готово =^_^=

Comment: Ну и последний вопрос, извиняюсь, - А для, допустим третьего пробела от начала? Я на самом деле давно мучаюсь этим вопросом и по-моему IndexOf умеет только первый разделительный знак понимать..

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko можно через цикл.

Comment: цикл - это уже не так лаконично, хотя тоже вариант. Неужели в powershell нет такой возможности отсчитывать разделительный знак в строке?